# Kotlin / SQLite delete() in batch issue

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I would like to delete mutiple items from SQLite in batch basing on their ID column.

What I have is a HashMap which contains objects which one of field is pID (unique ID in DB).

So, here's my code:

```
 /*
        Delete rows from DB
        */
        val selection = "${BaseColumns._ID} = ?"

        // Create a list of product ID's to delete
        val dbDeletor = dbHelper.writableDatabase

        // Temp array to store ID's in String format
        val tempIDs = ArrayList<String>()

        // Loop through array of items to be deleted
        for(i in ProductsRecyclerAdapter.productsToDeleteArray)
            tempIDs.add(i.value.pID.toString())

        // Perform deletion in DB
        val deletedRowsCount = dbDeletor.delete(ProductsEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, tempIDs.toTypedArray())

        // Show snackbar with count of deleted items
        Snackbar.make(mainCoordinatorLayout, "Products deleted: $deletedRowsCount", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Everything works great when I'm deleting only 1 item but if tempIDs array contains 2 or more I'm receiving following Exception:

> Too many bind arguments.  3 arguments were provided but the statement needs 1 arguments.

Maybe the reason is that I'm converting pID of type Long into String in order to delete rows in batch? I did not find any other solution. Please take a look and comment.

Comment: I think you have to use ˋinˋ instead of ˋ=ˋ in the val selection

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks somewhat like that:

```
DELETE FROM ProductsEntry.TABLE_NAME WHERE BaseColumns._ID = ?
```

There is only 1 argument `?` but you're passing 3 values (IDs). You want to use `IN` statement instead, and print your params separated by comma:

```
// IN instead of equal to compare multiple values
val selection = "${BaseColumns._ID} IN (?)"

// your code to obtain IDs here
// .....

// combine all values into single string, ie. 1, 2, 3, 4 and wrap it as an array
val selectionArg = arrayOf(tempIDs.joinToString())

// Perform deletion in DB
val deletedRowsCount = dbDeletor.delete(ProductsEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArg)
```